# Checking for empty for loops in C++

Tags: c++, templates, macros

Is it possible to check for empty for loops in C++, perhaps some clever template/macro trick? Seems like GCC does not support -Wempty-body for for loops.

Comment: The compiler itself might be able to when parsing the code and even optimize out a loop with an empty body. AFAIK, there's no way to tell a C++ program to analyze itself to make those sorts of checks.

Comment: "Check" in what way? What do you want to do when you "find" one? This is very unclear.

Comment: Give a warning during compilation for exampe.

Answer (score 4):

Look into static code analysis tools and their options. [CPPCheck](http://cppcheck.sourceforge.net/) is bundled with the [IDE](https://www.jetbrains.com/clion/) I use, performing static analysis before commits.

Comment: cppcheck does not by default pick up empty for loops: i.e., for(init; cond; post); but I'll see if there is a way to configure it to do so. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

What do you consider to be an empty for loop? This?

```
for(;;) {}
```

This?

```
for(;;);
```

How about this?

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i);
```

All of these forms are legal (`;` is considered an empty statement). The first two are equivalent to `while(true)` whereas the last one defines `i` and increments it 10 times. Historically, GCC doesn't optimize this away because `for(;;);` is a common pattern in kernels and other embedded programs at the end of `main()`.

However...

The following test case does produce warnings (indentation important):

```
int main()
{
    for (; 1<2; );
    {
      if (1==1);
    }
    while (1==1);
      return 0;
}

main.cpp: In function 'int main()':

main.cpp:4:9: warning: this 'for' clause does not guard... [-Wmisleading-indentation]

         for (; 1<2; );
         ^~~

main.cpp:5:11: note: ...this statement, but the latter is misleadingly indented as if it is guarded by the 'for'

           if (1==1);
           ^~

main.cpp:5:20: warning: suggest braces around empty body in an 'if' statement [-Wempty-body]

           if (1==1);
                    ^

main.cpp:6:9: warning: this 'while' clause does not guard... [-Wmisleading-indentation]

         while (1==1);
         ^~~~~

main.cpp:7:11: note: ...this statement, but the latter is misleadingly indented as if it is guarded by the 'while'

           return 0;
           ^~~~~~
```

Which means you should be fine if you're worried about a stray semi-colon and your code is properly indented.

Comment: I just want to warn about this kind of loop for(int; cond; post);

Answer (score 2):

In addition to [learvst](https://stackoverflow.com/users/276193/learnvst)'s recommendation for static analysis tool, an additional suggestion, if you are looking for these empty for loops for bug chasing.

There are many empty loops which are perfectly correct. For example:

```
for (auto it=v.begin(); it!=v.end() && *it!=val;  it++)
    ;
```

But there are some nasty ones caused by a `;` that is difficult to spot

```
for (auto it=v.begin(); it!=v.end(); it++);    // oops !!! 
    do_something(*v);
```

Fortunately, these kind of nasty bugs are often related to misleading indentation.  So you could use [GCC's 6 indentation](https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=GCC6-Misleading-Indentation) warnings `-Wmisleading-indentation`